# Deploy env file in test and qa

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

For setting the API URL and key value , i have created .env.development and .env.qa for test and QA environment. But how to deploy this file in azure devops,like how to setup the environemtn variable in pipeline.
can someone guide me through steps.

Comment: Is your project based on create-react-app?

Comment: yes it is.Also am using build configuration,not using YAML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully implemented the feature in Azure Devops.

I have created seperate zip file by creating new task for test and qa,buildid with the suffix mentioning the environment in the Build Pipeline. Similarly we need to mention the given zip folder name in Test and QA task in release pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar setup, multiple dotenv files for each environment. In the package.json, we've defined multiple build scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "build:test": "env-cmd --no-override .env.tst react-scripts build",
  "build:qa": "env-cmd --no-override .env.qa react-scripts build",
  "build:prod": "env-cmd --no-override .env.prod react-scripts build"
},
```

Don't use `.env.production` or `.env.test` however, otherwise, these will be used automatically by [react-scripts](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used) in every build or test command.

Comment: In this case,we need to create seperate build in devops for the each environment,right?

Comment: In Azure devops,i dont see the option to create seperate build file for each environment.In build pipeline, npm run build will create the build folder which will be deployed in the release pipeline.Can you explain how did you implement in you project.

Comment: Hmm, I've never worked with Azure DevOps, so I'm not sure if that is possible either. However, you are describing a single pipeline. Are all environments being build with the same pipeline?

Comment: Yes, We have single pipeline.

Comment: You will need to have some kind of control over the build command or environment variables for each build. If you currently have a single build which is getting deployed to all three environments, you probably have to change that to creating a build per environment.